# Draw circle vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

How  I can draw circle in VHDL?
There is  [my BDF design](http://oi48.tinypic.com/o7kfts.jpg)

Sow, I need to draw red circle ~ 100 px radius. I think I should use some vector, but how?

```
entity VGAFrameTest is
port(   yrow, xcolumn : in unsigned(9 downto 0); -- row and  column number of VGA video
        VGA_CLK : in std_logic;                -- pixel clock
        VGA_R, VGA_G, VGA_B: out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)); --  color information
end;

architecture rtl of VGAFrameTest is
constant COLOR_ON : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others=>'1'); 
constant COLOR_OFF : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
constant ROW_HEIGHT : integer := 480; -- number of visible rows
```

> ```
> -- A test of visible range is recommended
> -- VGA 640x480@60Hz resolution is not natural for LCD monitors
> -- They support it but some monitors do not display all columns
> -- 1 or 2 last columns can be missing
> ```

```
constant COLUMN_WIDTH : integer := 640 -1 ; -- number of visible columns - correction

begin
  frame:process(VGA_CLK)
  begin
  if rising_edge(VGA_CLK) then
        VGA_R<=COLOR_ON;VGA_G<=COLOR_ON;VGA_B<=COLOR_ON; --initilize  color to white  
        if (yrow = 240 and xcolumn = 320) then
          VGA_B<=COLOR_OFF; VGA_G<=COLOR_OFF; 
        elsif yrow = 1 or yrow = ROW_HEIGHT-2 or xcolumn=1 or xcolumn = COLUMN_WIDTH-2 then
          VGA_R<=COLOR_OFF; VGA_G<=COLOR_OFF; VGA_B<=COLOR_OFF; -- black frame
        elsif yrow = ROW_HEIGHT-1 then        
          VGA_B<=COLOR_OFF; VGA_G<=COLOR_OFF; --last  column is red
        end if;  
 end if;    
 end process;

end;
```

Comment: Potentially helpful search terms: bresenham, scanline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any radius by changing 157696 to (160000 - r^2)

480 and 640 is center of circle multiplied by 2

```
  begin
      frame:process(VGA_CLK)
      begin
      if rising_edge(VGA_CLK) then 
      VGA_R<=COLOR_OFF;VGA_G<=COLOR_OFF;VGA_B<=COLOR_OFF;
            if yrow>159 and yrow <320 and xcolumn < 440  and xcolumn > 199  then 
              VGA_B<=COLOR_ON; VGA_G<=COLOR_ON;VGA_R<=COLOR_ON;   

               if  (480*yrow-yrow*yrow+640*xcolumn-xcolumn*xcolumn )> 157696   then
              VGA_B<="0001001100"; VGA_G<=COLOR_OFF; VGA_R <= "1011111000";  
             end if;
            end if;  


 end if;    
 end process;
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is some variant on `X**2 + Y**2 = R**2;`
such as `Y = Sqrt(R**2 - X**2)`

the trick to an efficient implementation is to avoid expensive operations like sqrt, and minimise (slightly) expensive multiplications.

You could take a guess for Y, (start somewhere you know that Y would be 0), square it and compare to R**2 - X**2 for each new X, revising your guess when it is wrong by too much.
Martin's search terms will be helpful here.

The coordinate transforms to set the origin (0,0) at the right place on the screen are relatively easy.

Comment: Sorry, no more info from here. If you know enough VHDL to have written the code you originally posted, you know enough to complete the project from the hints in my answer.